# How to access host:port of a linux container from a windows container?

Tags: docker, docker-for-windows

Basically I'm trying to access a Linux container via a Windows one on the same machine. From what I've read so far the easiest way to to do this via the host and registered ports but I'm having no luck.

I'm running Docker Desktop on windows 10

I have a Linux container running (Elasticsearch) and I can access it on my windows machine via localhost:9200 and via the nat IP 192.168.224.1:9200

I'm now running 4.8-windowsservercore-ltsc2019 along side it but I can't access 192.168.224.1:9200 from there. I can ping the nat 192.168.224.1, but it fails when I curl 192.168.223.1:9200, it fails with a timeout.

The Linux container is created with a bunch of other services on their own bridge network.

I'm clearly missing something to allow my windows container access to my Linux ones.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add both containers to the same network, then you can have one container access the other using the container's name.
You can reuse your existing bridge network.

```
docker network create myNetwork
docker network connect myNetwork web1
docker network connect myNetwork web2
```

> https://stackoverflow.com/a/58764482/15142953

As for 192.168.224.1, it's the IP address of the NAT gateway, not the address that the containers use within their network.